# How to copy several text to clipboard with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got all elements which contains checked checkbox. when click button it copies the text which has checked checkbox to clipboard. my code works well, but it copies only text of one element. I want to copy  as much as i check. can someone help me please?

here is my code

```
  $( ".copy" ).click(function() {
                    $('.LC20lb').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {                     
                      var inp = $("<input>");
                      $("body").append(inp);
                      inp.val($(this).text()).select();
                      document.execCommand("copy");
                      inp.remove();


                      })
```

Comment: When you say, *"text of checkbox"* do mean the value that the user doesn't see? Or do you mean the text users can see as a label or just text that's next to a checkbox? If the latter, then that text doesn't actually belong to the checkbox. You should post some HTML as well because I see you are appending inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Build a variable in each iteration to get text from all the checkboxes, then use that value to copy:

```
$( ".copy" ).click(function() {
  var inp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append(inp);
  var str = ""

  $('.LC20lb').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {                     
     str+= $(this).text()
  })

  inp.val(str).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  inp.remove();
})
```

Comment: @SalomeSulaberidze You can accept the answer if it helped you by clicking on the grey tick next to the answer, which turns green on clicking. It adds reputation to both you and the answerer :)

Comment: @SalomeSulaberidze You need to click on the grey tick on the left of the answer, right below the up/down arrows to mark it as accepted. (Not on the left of this comment, but the answer given above)

Comment: @SalomeSulaberidze Alas..I'm tired of explaining to you how to accept an answer..hope you discover that fine art someday. :)